# How to insert binary file into a binary SQL column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a table containing an `image` column.

Any idea how to write query to insert bin file to the image field?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Where from, where to, what langauge is your application in? THe last is important for sample code is that is from an application. Right now - TSQL alone wont really be used for binary inserts in 99% of the cases without something around it.

Comment: FILESTREAM is something you might benefit from knowing something about. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with `marc_s`.

But your query will be something like this.

```
INSERT yourtable(ImageColumn)
SELECT image FROM
OPENROWSET(BULK, 'filename.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS blobtable(image)
```

Comment: BUT: That is bad practice noramlly as it assumes the file is reachable FROM THE SERVER - not whatever application you run it in. Better: load it in your application and then move it via prameterized query.

Comment: @TomTom OK, I fully agree with you, but, maybe, OP wants load files to DB by SSMS in test purpose.

Comment: Well, maybe he likes eating Pizza. Irrelevant. SSMS etc. is something he is respsonsible for mentioning, not me for assuming. SImple like that. I assume the 95% of all use cases: an application writing data to the Server, not the 5% edge case.

Comment: OK. But this 5% also have the right to life. Question is very concrete and not about best practice and design. And i gave concrete answer.

Comment: Yes, and I expect those fringe cases to be named. Not someone making gross statements because somewhere in some cases it makes sense. your approach in normal applications is a reason to send you to HR to talk about incompetence. This answer should not be in a general question.

Comment: "Heck there are 2 people on the planet that need" ha-ha-ha. Concretely the OP and i gave him concrete answer.